# How to call a static Method in Laravel Translatable package on per model basis

Tags: laravel, laravel-translatable

I am using this package for managing translations in a Laravel project.
The resulting output of an API endpoint is as shown in the image with translation array.

In there documentation (link: https://docs.astrotomic.info/laravel-translatable/package/methods#static-disableautoloadtranslations) it is mentioned we can disable this translation array on entire project from config file or disable per model using this function `static disableAutoloadTranslations()`. I am not sure how to call this on a per model basis?

[image]

```
    namespace App\Models;
    use Astrotomic\Translatable\Translatable;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

    class Category extends Model{
    
    use Translatable, SoftDeletes;
    public $translatedAttributes = ['title'];

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public $guard_name = 'admin';

    public function getIconAttribute($value)
    {
        return ($value != null) ? Storage::disk('public')->url($value) : null;
    }

    self::disableAutoloadTranslations();

}
```

Comment: Can you show your Model code? If you are using Translatable trait in your Model (use \Dimsav\Translatable\Translatable) , you just need to write: 'self::disableAutoloadTranslations()'

Comment: @mmarques I imported the Trait, but I am not sure how to add that in model, when I put in model self::disableAutoloadTranslations();    
 "message": "syntax error, unexpected 'self' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)",

Comment: Please show your Model code so we can try to help you.

Comment: @mmarques updated question with Model code

Comment: could you add your controller method that calls this data?

Comment: @mmarques         return Category::disableAutoloadTranslations()->get();, when I write like this it returns error (Call to a member function get() on null), but Category::get() returns result with translation array.

Comment: @mmarques got another work around which solves the problem, disabled translations by default from config, then loaded in controller using eagerloading like :        
 return Category::with('translations')->get();  This solves the problem but not sure how to do it the other way.

Comment: @mmarques same issue is mentioned here also: https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable/pull/484 but when I call Post::disableAutoloadTranslations() it returns null.

Comment: @abhiklpm the disableAutoloadTranslations returns void as you can see here: https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable/blob/79ca742f7c2189770faacfa655ca4f71851f8f1e/src/Translatable/Translatable.php#L573

Comment: @abhiklpm and in your model you should call your self::disableAutoloadTranslations(); inside the Model boot. Example: public static function boot() {
    parent::boot(); self::disableAutoloadTranslations(); }

Comment: @mmarques thankyou, I will try